# How to check for unviewable chars in text file using Linux shell

Tags: bash, shell

When I type this in Ubuntu:

```
# cat -A my.config
```

It outputs:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

But for:

```
# cat my.config
```

nothing shows up in the terminal.

So from bash, how can you tell if a file contains those strange characters?

Thanks!

Comment: They're NUL bytes. But if you could test for them, what would you do with that information?

Comment: Use the `file` command, it will tell you if the file is a text file or something else.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using Unix.

Comment: Interactively, you *already know how* -- you're showing that fact in the question itself! So what's the _actual_ question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters are `NULL` bytes. You can search for them on a file with:

```
grep -Pa '\x00' /folder/file
```

You may also search for all non-ASCII characters on a file with this:

```
grep -Pa "[\x80-\xFF]" /folder/file
```

Finally, you could check for all non-ASCII characters on all files in a folder with the following code:

```
grep -Pa -r "[\x80-\xFF]" /folder
```

**Note**: the core of this answer relies on `grep -P`, which might not be available on all `grep` versions. Also, from `grep man` about the `-P` option:

> -P, --perl-regexp
>       Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression. This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.

Comment: *grumbles about use of GNUisms without explicit caveat or warning*

Comment: @Charles: Is it better now? If you think another caveat should be added please comment again.

Comment: Yup. (I was trying to decide whether to bring this up at all, since the OP explicitly specifies "Linux" in the title, and GNU grep is most common there -- but then, there are quite a lot of embedded Linux systems running Busybox, or a few running GNU grep compiled without the optional -- meaning, not-always-compiled-in even with latest GNU grep -- PCRE support).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "viewable" class in your post matches `grep` ["graph"](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) class, this should work

```
grep -la "[^[:graph:]]"
```

Comment: There are actually stronger guarantees that this will be available than the GNU-specific documentation you linked to -- the `graph` character class is part of [POSIX BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05), so absent `-a` this answer would be guaranteed to work on all POSIX platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Octal dump is your friend:

```
od -c my.config
```